# flexbox container two divs responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

How I can make responsive `flexbox`?

So I use `flexbox` and two divs, one for leftside and one for right side.
Screen is like splitted, left side is image and right side info and inputs.

But left side isn't responsive if `ajax` loads more data, then white space is coming under the image.

My HTML:

```
<div class="forny-container">
    <div class="forny-inner">
        <div class="forny-two-pane">
            <div></div> <!-- form div -->
            <div></div> <!-- image div -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.fo-container {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    height:100%;
}

.fo-inner {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.fo-two-pane {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.fo-two-pane > div {
    flex: 1;
}

.fo-two-pane > div:first-child {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
}

.fo-two-pane > div:last-child {
    background: url('http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/9/9/0/722477-best-barber-wallpapers-1920x1080-samsung-galaxy.jpg') center center no-repeat
        hsla(31, 80%, 93%, 1);
    display: none;
}
```

If `ajax` loads more data or error messages into form div then white space is coming under the image:

[image: white space under image]

What is going wrong?

Comment: You trying to do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57642783/1210271

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should solve your problem. Here the working code.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.image-selector {
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightpink;
}

.right h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="left">
      <h1>Left</h1>
      <img class="image-selector" src="https://agentpekka.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/AP_MVM_Apple_2x-640x854.jpg" alt="image">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <h1>Right</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <h3>Subheading</h3>
      <h4>Somecontent</h4>
      <lable>Name:</lable>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name">
      <p>description goes here, some more content</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[Click for Codepen link](https://codepen.io/junaydk/full/MWgJorV)

Additionally, you will need to use Media Queries for handling different screen sizes and different view ports.

Comment: It is not 100% height.. left side image fixed height, like if you scroll then it doesnt matter left image size.